# Laravel eloquent many to many relation deep conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, wherehas

I have two Model named `Product` and `Category`. Admin can change the status of `Product` and `Category`.
Here `Product` and `Category` has many to many relations. So that, all `Product` can belongs to multiple `Category`

Now at my user panel,
I want to show that all `Product` whose all `Category`'s status is active.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, got all the products that have all the categories active. First time I thought complicated so I didn't solve.

```
$products = Product::whereDoesntHave('catagories',function($category){
    $category->where('status','!=',1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
$products = Product::with('category')
    ->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'active'); // use your column & condition
    })
  ->get();
```

Comment: Must you have use relation in your Product model.
 
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

Comment: It returns all products that has one category is activated. I need those products, what has all category is activated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your product model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, CategoryProduct::class, 'product_id', 'category_id');
//->withPivot([]); if you need anything from the pivot table for any reason you can add the column names in the array
}
```

this is assuming that the pivot table have the columns product_id and category_id

```
$products = Product::with('categories')
    ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('categories.status', 'active');
    })
  ->get();
```

inside the where the word categories is the table name

Comment: It returns all products that has one category is activated. I need those products, what has all category is activated.